# create an ordered dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict like:

```
original_dict = {'two':'2','three':'3','one':'1','foo':'squirrel'}
```

And I wanted two be in this order:

`ordered_dict = OrderedDict({'one':'1','two':'2','three':'3','foo':'squirrel'`})

but I don't get the same order,
`{'one':'1','two':'2','three':'3','foo':'squirrel'}` creates a dict by itself so it doesn't work as I spected

I saw in the documentation that the sorted method can be used

```
OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: len(t[0])))
```

But I don't know a function to return the order I want 
I tried

```
ordered_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(original_dict.items(),['one','two','three','foo']))
```

But that didn't work.

Note that the order I want can be quite arbitrary, like:

```
['three','foo','one','two',]
```

Comment: Just insert them all one at a time. Do you have a particularly large list?

Comment: not that  much, about 30 items.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
order=['one','two','three','foo']
ordered_dict = OrderedDict((k, original_dict[k]) for k in order)
```